# Creating generic types with enum values

Tags: c#, .net, generics, design-patterns, enums

I'd like to be able to create new generic types using enum values. I believe this is possible with C++ templates, but I don't know if it's possible to do with C#.

So what I'd like to do is:

```
public class MyClass <T>
{
  public void Do<T>() {} 
}

public enum Metals
{
  Silver, Gold
}
```

and I'd like to pass in an enum like:

```
var myGoldClass = new MyClass<Metals.Gold>();
```

I guess I could create classes called Gold, Silver to achieve this, but I quite like having an enum to constrain the types of my generic class.

The reason I want something like this in the real world is I'm creating an event aggregator (a publish-subscribe model) and I'd want my subscribers to subscribe to messages of a certain type T. So i thought it would be nice if i could have my subscribers subscribe using enums.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, Metals.Gold is just an example enum. I'd like the client library to create their own enums\classes and use it instead. I'm not defining the enum myself.

Comment: Not possible because an enum value is not a type.

Comment: Yup, that was what I feared. I'm still open to something that could emulate the idea.

Comment: you will have to add a paremeter : ``public void Do<T>(T item) {}`` and may use it like : ``MyClass<Metals>();`` and ``myGoldClass.Do(Metals.Gold)``

Comment: I feel I should clarify my previous statement: The type of a value of an enum is the type of the enum itself. (Still doesn't help you though.)

Comment: @RB - The link you sent (http://blog.falafel.com/introducing-type-safe-enum-pattern/ ) seems to be perfectly good idea. I could create a base enum class and have users derive and extend that enum, although it seems a bit cludgy.

Comment: Why not pass the enum value as a constructor parameter?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - The trouble will be in my subscriber, as I'll not be able to "target" classes of Message <T> in that case. Nevertheless, a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using enum values as generic parameters is not possible. In cases like that you should probably use inheritance:

```
public abstract class Metal
{
    protected Metals MetalType { get; private set; }

    protected Metal(Metals metal)
    {
        MetalType = metal;
    }
}

public class Gold : Metal
{
    public Gold() : base(Metals.Gold)
    {
    }
}
```

Going further, the part of the question about PubSub implementation is too broad as a lot of things should be taken in consideration. Here is an example where you may some useful ideas:

```
public class EventHub
{
    // only one receiver per message type is allowed to simplify an example
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<MessageTypes, IReceiver> receivers = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<MessageTypes, IReceiver>();

    public bool TrySubscribe(MessageTypes messageType, IReceiver receiver)
    {
        return receivers.TryAdd(messageType, receiver);
    }

    public void Publish(IMessage message)
    {
        IReceiver receiver;

        if (receivers.TryGetValue(message.MessageType, out receiver))
        {
            receiver.Receive(message);
        }
    }
}

public interface IMessage
{
    MessageTypes MessageType { get; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public interface IReceiver
{
    void Receive(IMessage message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pub-sub part, but I had already worked that out. In the end, I created a base class as a constraint in my event aggregator and using derivates of that (for eg. your Gold class) as message type differentiators.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as T as to be a Type and not a value.

Maybe I don't understand your problem but why don't you do something like that :

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Metals _metal;

    public MyClass(Metals metal)
    {
        _metal = metal;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        //using _metal here
    }
}

var myGoldClass = new MyClass(Metals.Gold);
```

Comment: The reason I didn't use this route is that MyClass (Metals.Gold) is the same as MyClass (Metals.Silver) when passed as a generic type parameter.